# Google Chart chartArea Opacity?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How do I set chartArea opacity? Here is a piece of my code... any ideas would be helpful. Thanks!

```
        // Column Chart
              function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'In Millions'],
      ['2010',  178.7],
      ['2011',  211.693],
      ['2012',  199.3]
    ]);

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
        draw(data,
             {title:"",
              width:400, height:400,
              colors:['#89a7bf', '#b19237', '#698322', '#bf855d', '#196364', '#CCCCCC', '#D64646', '#8E468E'],
              legend: {position: 'bottom', width:"250", textStyle: {fontSize: 10}},
              hAxis: {title: "Year"}}
        );
  }


  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Comment: hi again, what do you mean with opacity? do you want the full chart to be kind of transparent ?

Comment: I mean the ColumnChart bars transparent at approx 30% to see through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry, the option `areaOpacity` is only available in the following charts:

> Visualization: Geochart
>
> Visualization: Area Chart
>
> Visualization: Combo Chart
>
> Visualization: Bubble Chart
>
> Visualization: Motion Chart
>
> Visualization: Stepped Area Chart

For the above charts, google says:

> The default opacity of the colored area under an area chart series,
>   where 0.0 is fully transparent and 1.0 is fully opaque. To specify
>   opacity for an individual series, set the areaOpacity value in the
>   series property.

Comment: Yes I now see this option is not possible. thanks for the info.

Comment: I would like to see an example of how to use it with the supported charts, please